# Ruth-Aaron triples, etc

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, open-problems

A *[Ruth-Aaron pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth%E2%80%93Aaron_pair)* is two numbers $(n,n+1)$ such that
their sum of prime factors is equal, counting repeated prime factors.
(The name refers to Hank Aaron's 715 homeruns surpassing Babe Ruth's 714!)
So
$$15 = 3 \cdot 5 \;;\; 3+5 = 8$$
$$16 = 2^4 \;;\; 2+2+2+2 = 2 \cdot 4 = 8$$
The notion can be generalized:
$$417,162 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 251 \cdot 277 \;;\; 2+3+251+277 = 533$$
$$417,163 = 17 \cdot 53 \cdot 463 \;;\; 17+53+463 = 533$$
$$417,164 = 2^2 \cdot 11 \cdot 19 \cdot 499 \;;\; 2+2+11+19+499 = 533$$
My question is:

> **Q**. Are there $k$-tuples, for all $k \ge 2$, for which there exists at least
>   one $n$ such that $(n, n+1, n+2, \ldots, n+k)$
>   has the same sum of prime factors (counting repeated prime factors as above)?

---

***Addendum***. I was out of date, relying on a "claimed proof by Erdős" that there
were an infinite number of R-A pairs, which turned out not
to be sound, as Benjamin Dickman explained. So the problem is open even for pairs,
let alone $k$-tuples.

Apparently no Ruth-Aaron quadruple is known.
David Stork wrote [Mathematica search code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69635/194) and found there are no such quadruples up to $10^{10}$.

Comment: Did Erdos ever meet either Ruth or Aaron?

Comment: @WillJagy Actually, Erdos is known (in a piece of mathematical folklore) as having met Aaron and signed a baseball together, as reported by Pomerance (mentioned in my answer below). See [**here**](http://web.archive.org/web/20061205223134/http://www.oakland.edu/enp/related.html): "Carl Pomerance (now at Dartmouth College), who had a long and fruitful collaboration with Paul, reports having a baseball autographed by both of them, occasioned by their both having received honorary degrees at Emory University in 1995" in connection with the Ruth-Aaron numbers asked about.

Comment: I'm sure Erdos has Ruth, Aaron, and Bacon numbers.

Comment: It  is conjectured that the converse relationship holds.

Comment: JO'R: Apparently only two triples are known. Besides what you list in your post, the other known one is: 6913943284, 6913943285, 6913943286 ([**source**](http://chesswanks.com/seq/a039752.txt)). That link checks up to at least 532,320,600,592 (I had to "stop" the page because it was very slow to load!) so I think you would need to look pretty far to find a quadruple.

Comment: Apparently, here's a picture of Erdos and Aaron: http://www2.math.ou.edu/~jalbert/courses/hank_erdos.png

Comment: It seems that, contra Hoffman, Erdos never claimed to prove the infinitude of Ruth--Aaron pairs. After the original Ruth--Aaron paper appeared in the Journal of Recreational Mathematics, Pomerance learned of Erdos's interest from a letter (not a phone call). In the letter, Erdos says he can prove that the Ruth--Aaron numbers have density $0$. Far from claiming a proof that there are infinitely many Ruth--Aaron numbers, Erdos says that problem "seems hopeless" ! The original letter is available online --- see the very first scan at
http://www.cah.utexas.edu/collections/math_erdos.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Observe that a positive answer to your question would imply that there are infinitely many Ruth-Aaron pairs; however, this infinitude already constitutes an open question.

Consult:

> De Koninck, J. M. (2004). Computational Results and Queries in Number Theory. *Annales Univ. Sci. Budapest., 23*. pp. 149-161. [**Link**](http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_023_2004/149.pdf) (no paywall).

Excerpt (p. 152):

[image]

The paper does go on to provide a heuristic argument for a generalized problem in the same direction as your question, though it is in the context of $\beta$ rather than $S$.

Another excerpt (pp. 153-154):

[image]

(See the aforelinked citation for the argument.)

Comment: Ah, I was out of date, due to "[an erroneous claimed proof by Erdős](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ruth-AaronPair.html)" that there were an infinite number of Ruth-Aaron pairs. Thanks for the correction and update!

Comment: (Note that I was "counting repeated prime factors," which increases the solutions, but still leaves matters quite open.)